# Button Onclick automatically called when press back button from next activity

Tags: android, back-button

my question is i have set button color as white as default button  and in  onclick event i have set yellow as background of this button  in onCreate method of First Activity class and after clicking this button i go to next  activity and from next activity,i press android back button,  Button color is shown yellow to me not white one as default. How to resolve this.

```
        final Button myButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
 myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eee83e"));
                Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Whats is your question exaclty? You want to change the button color once you come back from the activity you opened? If so, trigger the code in onResume of your first activity

Comment: Didn't understand the question.. what seems to be the problem?

Comment: You should maybe remember the color of the button before you go to the next activity and then restore it onResume in your first activity. it doesn't make sense to trigger a button click when you get back cause it will move you to the next activity immediately.

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0):

do this `onResume()` to set again your button background color white like..

```
   myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("Whitecolor code..."));
```